# Elastic Bean Stalk - Failed to add user

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to add celery service to elastic bean stalk environment. So I decided to create first user and group "celery". I follow instructions from page http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-users, and I created config:

```
groups:
  celery:
    gid: "101"

users:
  celery:
    groups:
      - celery
    uid: "1501"
    homeDir: "/opt/python/celery"
```

But during deploy, I get error:

```
[2017-02-10T08:59:23.899Z] INFO  [16595] - [Application update app-43a4-170210_095832@474/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild] : Activity execution failed, because: Failed to add user celery (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

I also was modifing homeDir, and uid, and login, and gruop id, but it doesn't help. How to fix it? Or how to debug useradding by elastic bean stalk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround by 404pio offers a solution, but the `ignoreErrors` set to `true` can hide surprise errors.

I commented on that answer, but formatting is limited and gets hard to understand. Here is a way to improve on error cases:

```
groups:
  celery:
    gid: "101"

commands:
  command 00_add_user_celery:
    test: test ! "`id -u celery 2> /dev/null`"
    command: useradd -d /opt/python/celery -g celery -u 1501 celery
    ignoreErrors: false
```

`ignoreErrors: false` is the default and could also be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround with commands sections:

```
groups:
  celery:
    gid: "101"

commands:
  command 00_add_user_celery:
    command: useradd -d /opt/python/celery -g celery -u 1501 celery
    ignoreErrors: true
```

Comment: I prefer setting `ignoreErrors` to `false` to avoid surprises. To make the script work, then, you can rely on the test option. Just add something like `test: test ! "`id -u celery 2> /dev/null`"` to the command section.